# Is this a correct Implemenation of the Singleton Pattern?

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

The following code is my implementation of the Singleton Pattern.

```
 #include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Uncopyable
{
protected:
    Uncopyable(){}
    ~Uncopyable(){}
private:
    Uncopyable(const Uncopyable<T>&);
    Uncopyable& operator=(const Uncopyable<T>&);
};

template <class T>
class Singleton : private Uncopyable<T>
{
public:
    static T* getInstancePtr()
    {
        return instance;
    }
protected:
    Singleton<T>()
    {
        if(instance == 0)
        {
            instance = new T();
        }
    };
    ~Singleton<T>()
    {

    };
private:
    static T* instance;
};
template<class T> T* Singleton<T>::instance = 0;

class Test : public Singleton<Test>
{
public:
    Test(){};
    ~Test(){};
    inline void test() const
    {
        std::cout << "Blah" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    friend class Singleton<Test>;
protected:
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test* t = Test::getInstancePtr();
    Test* t2 = Test::getInstancePtr();

    t->test();
    t2->test();

    return 0;
}
```

It works in this form, however I am uncertain as to whether it really is correct due to the constructor and destructor of the Singleton being protected as opposed to being private. If I declare them as private the code will not compile as they are not accessible to the class. Is this implementation safe to use, or is there anything I can do to improve it to ensure only one instance will be created and used.

Thanks

Comment: The Singleton pattern should be avoided at all costs!!!

Comment: Why `Uncopyable` is a class template?

Comment: @Phorce I know the ins and outs of using it, that isn't the point of this question however.

Comment: @Phorce, that's very debatable.

Comment: Put the constructor code inside `getInstancePtr()` to get the advantage of lazy initialization. Possibly you can make `instance = new T();` thread safe, which is executed only once in a lifetime.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall It is, however, from personal experience it's just best to stay clean IMO :)! Design Patterns are useful, but, most of the times, I do design patterns (facade etc..) without even realising

Comment: Well, it isn't thread safe for one, `if(instance == 0)` could be subject to race conditions.

Comment: Code review questions are off-topic here.  This might be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Singleton is so easy to implement that if you inherit to get it... you are doing it wrong => it takes less typing to repeat the `GetInstance()` method for each type than to repeat the inheritance and friend declaration. **Note: the constructors and destructor of the singleton should be private**.

Comment: @Phorce: "At all costs" is overstating a tiny bit.  A very tiny bit.  There could be legitimate use cases.  But it should not be used in about 99.99% of the places where it's currently used, and most people should not even be considering it.  Damn the GoF for even freaking *mentioning* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the code you've posted.

1. The `Uncopyable` class doesn't need to be templated
2. The `Singleton` class isn't thread safe
3. Your `Singleton` instance is never deleted

I would re-implement your accessor as:

```
static T& GetInstance()
{
    static T instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Then make sure you call `Singleton<T>::GetInstance()` in the main thread of your application (during initialisation) to avoid any threading issues.

Comment: I think you need `instance` to be static.

Comment: Surely you don't mean to return a new T object each time GetInstance is called?

Comment: Oops. Thanks for spotting the deliberate typo... ;)

Comment: Thanks that getInstance method works nicely. Just a point however, what is so bad about the Uncopyable class being a template? Is it preference or just plain bad?

Comment: It's not preference, or being bad, it's just unnecessary. You've created a templated class that uses a templated type `T`, and then you never use it!

Answer (score 7):

That is most certainly an incorrect implementation of singleton. There are too many issues with that implementation.

In C++11, you can make use of [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) and [`std::once_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) to implement singleton pattern. Here is one example:

```
//CRTP base singleton class

template<typename TDerived>
class Singleton 
{
    static std::unique_ptr<TDerived> m_instance;
    static std::once_flag            m_once;

protected:     

    Singleton() {}

public:

    ~Singleton() { }

    static TDerived & GetInstance() 
    {
        std::call_once
        ( 
           Singleton::m_once, 
           [] (){ Singleton::m_instance.reset( new TDerived() ); }
        );
        return *m_instance;
    }
};

template<typename TDerived> 
std::unique_ptr<TDerived>  Singleton<TDerived>::m_instance;

template<typename TDerived> 
std::once_flag   Singleton<TDerived>::m_once;
```

Now you can derive from it as:

```
class Demo : public Singleton<Demo>
{
     public:
          void HelloWorld() { std::cout << "HelloWorld" << std::endl; }
};

//call HelloWorld() function through singleton instance!
DemoSingleton::GetInstance().HelloWorld();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look further into these features of C++11

Comment: How would you then use this Singleton class to create a the Test class as a singelton. Im am unfamiliar with lamdas etc, and would appreciate a small example of using this form of a singleton.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was close with what I had tried myself, but now I understand it much better. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

your destructor private will cause the compile error?cause when the process ends,the compile cannot call the private function so the object cannot be delete

Answer (score 1):

No this is not a good implementation of the singleton pattern, it does not work!
The only instance of Test in the example is NULL! The constructor is never called!

You need to change Singleton::getInstancePtr to:

```
public:
    static T* getInstancePtr()
    {
        if(instance == 0)
        {
            instance = new T();
        }
        return instance;
    }
protected:
   Singleton<T>() {};
```

The constructor for Test will now be called.

Answer (score 0):

Usually singleton objects live for the lifetime of the program, so I do not implement them like that, because you use dynamic allocation, then someone must free it and you return a pointer to your singleton object, then you may accidentally delete it, so I will use something like this:

```
template< class T >
struct Singleton : Uncopyable<T> {
public:
    static T& get_instance() {
        static T res;
        use( res ); // make sure object initialized before used
        return res;
    }
private:
    static void use( T& ) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct implementation of the Singleton anti-pattern in C++.

The main issues with this attempt are:

- The semantics are a very weird and error-prone; you must instantiate `Singleton` somewhere in order to create the instance. You example never creates the instance, and `t->test()` is erroneously calling a function via a null pointer.
- Construction is not thread-safe; two instances could be created if two unsynchronised threads both instantiate `Singleton`.
- If the instance is actually created, then it is leaked.

A less erroneous implementation might be more like this:

```
template <typename T>
T & singleton()
{
    static T instance;
    return instance;
}
```

but this still has issues: in particular, the instance may be destroyed before other static objects, which may attempt to access it in their destructors.

Comment: Though the 3rd point can be trivially fixed by deleting in destructor, it's still debatable as the singleton object remains for the lifetime and an OS will collect it when the program ends.

Comment: @iammilind: Deleting it in the destructor would be a very bad idea, since there's nothing to stop multiple instances of `Singleton` all thinking they own the underlying instance. I agree that it's debatable whether (finite) resource leaks are a problem; but that's very much off topic. I just point it out as an issue that some people might be concerned about.